# jQuery one element event influence another

Tags: jquery, focus, hide, show

What Im trying to achive is to show/hide one div if input field somewhere is focused. Show  works but it wont hide it. Im new to jQuery

I cant figure it out whats wrong in my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($("#a").has(":focus")){
        $("#b").css("visibility","visible");}
    else {
        $("#b").css("visibility","hidden");}
});
```

html:

```
   <ul>
<li id="a" >
    <div class="label">
        <label id="company" class="description" for="company">Company</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="inputcompany" name="company" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
</li>
<li id="b" style="visibility: hidden;">
    <div class="label">
        <label class="description" for="company">Name </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="company" name="company" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
    </div> 
</li>
```

Sorry guys, secon li should have been with id "b".

Comment: You need this to happen in response to some user event, right? As it stands, the test is applied once, when the document loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#a input').focus(function() {
  $("#b").css("visibility","visible");
}).blur(function() {
   $("#b").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The javascript code will only be executed once. It seems as if you want an event handler - code that will be executed whenever `#a` loses/gains focus.

```
$('#a').focus(function() {
  $("#b").css("visibility","visible");
}).blur(function() {
   $("#b").css("visibility","hidden");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your doing it the wrong way if you want to show the next li when `hovering` the first one, I'll do it like that :

```
//For example on mouseover the #a
$('#a').on({
    mouseover:function() {
        $('#b').css("visibility","visible"); //we show the #b
    },
    //on mouseleave
    mouseleave: function() {
        if($('#a').find('input').val().length == 0) { //if nothing was entered in the first input
            $('#b').css("visibility","hidden"); //hide the #b
        }
    }
});
```

See a [live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/G83fS/).

Hope that's help.